# Limit of an integration formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth real (or complex) valued function defined on $S^2$. Then a direct calculation shows that
$$\int_{S^2}f(x)e^{ixy}\, dx=-\frac{i}{\|y\|}e^{i\|y\|}f\left(\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right)+\frac{i}{\|y\|}e^{-i\|y\|}f\left(-\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right)$$
where $y$ is a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $xy$ is the inner product of $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Clearly, if $f$ is a constant function, then the limit of right hand at $y=0$ equals the value of the left hand side. My question is whether it is possible to use the above equality to the find the value of the the left hand side at $y=0$, that is when there is no oscillation, for any $f$.

Comment: If I suppose the formula is right for $y\in S^2$ (but for $y\in S^2$, why to write the denominators on the right?), is there any reason to believe it is right for $\|y\|<1$?

Comment: The formula is correct for any nonzero $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Thanks for bringing my attention to the typo.

Comment: Are you sure? If you take $y$ to be very close to zero, and $f(y/\|y\|)\neq f(-y/\|y\|$, then the right hand side seems to grow unlimited..

Comment: I didn't compute it but it seems to me, as I wrote before, that, if $f(y/\|y\|)\neq f(-y/\|y\|)$, then the "cosines" in the right don't cancel and RHS($\epsilon y$) is unbounded as $\epsilon\to 0$, while the LHS it not. Or do I miss something?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. For eg, if $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)=x_3$, the LHS is zero when $t=0$, as expected, but the RHS blows up. Also when $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)=x_3^2$, the LHS is $4\pi/3$ when $t=0$ as one expects from the theory of Gamma functions. (Integrals of polynomials over spheres are expressible in terms of Gamma functions, and more or less easily computable.) I am embarrassed to realize that the above "equality" is incorrect. Maybe the reason that it works for constant functions is that the stationary phase method gives the right answer.http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~esiprpr/esi744.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any way of editing the problem without changing it completely. But I would appreciate it if someone could let me know about a possible "correction" to the RHS of the above formula.

Comment: Show us your "direct calculation", so that we understand what your "dx" is. Whatever it is, the left hand side is a continuous function of $y$, and its value at $y=0$ is $=\int_{S^2} f(x)\>dx$.